# SaSS import on click - refresh and apply on click

Tags: javascript, sass, zurb-foundation

Goal: To click a button that will re-compile my SaSS with a new @import option implemented.
Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? As obviously you cannot import after build time. So is the solution refresh and apply different @import?

I've attempt if statements in sass and changing the var through JS but too messy. eg:
    `var_theme1: true;`

```
@if $var__theme = true {
   @import 'themes/theme-1';
} @else {
   @import 'themes/theme-1';
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a button that compiles `.scss` files to `.css` when clicking it. In that case, which Sass compiler are you using?

Also, there might be an easier solution if you explain what problem you are really trying to solve. I.e. is the point to toggle between `@import` values in your CSS?

Comment: Hey there, I'm using gulp as my sass compiler and yes, on click switch to "defined theme" and re-compile. Wanting to make this function very flexible at the same time. Multiple themes that on click switches @import in settings config and then re-compile which should in turn apply the new theme.

Comment: EG:
    `function applyTheme () {
       if ("themeSwitch-button", click) {
         -- new sass import function --
        apply then refresh/re-compile with new option
    window.location.reload();
      } 
    }`

@Trollsyn

Comment: But the problem is that function is a javascript function that will run in the browser and will not have access to change the sass variables because they don't exist at this point. The browser only loads the compiled CSS (it will not load the original Sass files and variables.

So somehow need to re-define settings after click..

Comment: You might be able to use https://github.com/medialize/sass.js to access the file system and do your compiling.